# Java System Properties defined in eclipse.ini is not accessible in Java runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a build.xml containing an ANT task(which is an eclipse plugin) which does import operations. During this import I want to read some system properties which are specified in eclipse.ini. For example -Dmyprop=value.

When I execute build.xml in my local, system properties are accessible and everything works fine. When the build.xml is triggered from Azure pipeline the java system properties are not available to the JVM. No matter where the build.xml is triggered from it always starts the eclipse runtime and uses the same eclipse.ini file but why is the system properties accessible in first case and not the other?

Comment: What is the task doing exactly? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't explain why that happens but why not simply copy those props from the ini file into build.xml?. Incidentally, key->value pairs in an ini file are not really the same as system properties as they are taken from a file and generally don't use the shell

Comment: The purpose of `eclipse.ini` is to configure Eclipse itself, not for providing properties to some other software. Why would anyone even want to make an Ant build dependent on an Eclipse configuration?